# Jquery parent's span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I output the text to the parent `<div>`'s `<span>`? What am i doing wrong?
If there are any better solutions than working with spans and `.parent()`, please let me know.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<span></span> <!--the span where i want to output "troll" and "dwarf"-->
<a href="#" class="heroes" alt="troll">Icon</a>
<a href="#" class="heroes" alt="dwarf">Icon</a>
</div>

<div>
<span></span <!--the span where i want to output "witch"-->
><a href="#" class="heroes" alt="witch">Icon</a>
</div>

<div> 
<span></span> <!--etc...-->
<a href="#" class="heroes" alt="barbarian">Icon</a>
</div>

<div>
<span></span>
<a href="#" class="heroes" alt="necromancer">Icon</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.heroes').hover(function() {
    var hero = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).parent('span').text(hero);
}, function() {
    $(this).parent('span').text("");
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this).siblings('span').text(hero);
```

The span is a sibling of the anchor, not it's parent.

Indent your HTML, and you see it very easily:

```
<div> <!--The parent of the span and anchors!-->
    <span></span> <!--Sibling of the anchors!-->
    <a href="#" class="heroes" alt="troll">Icon</a>
    <a href="#" class="heroes" alt="dwarf">Icon</a>
</div>
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cXr29/3/)

**Note:** `alt` isn't a valid HTML attribute for an anchor.

Comment: "Note: alt isn't a valid HTML attribute for an anchor." Will that cause any problems? What do you suggest instead of alt?

Comment: Also, about "hero" wasn't defined in this function". I want the text to dissapear after i leave the element area, so thats why hero is not needed. Only empty string. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('span').text(hero);
```

`<span>` is sibling not parent of your links, you can find it based on actual `<div>` parent.

Comment: `siblings('span')`... Don't go up to go down... :)